# How to convert the timestamps column into Unix epoch format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I have the column of timestamps in my dataframe as shown below :

```
Timestamp

2021-04-22T10:17:20.648Y
2010-05-22T10:13:28.675Z
2001-04-22T10:17:20.648Z
      .
      .
```

I want to extract the time which should be in unix epoch format as shown below :

```
Timestamp

1147889044
1147870044
1879850044
.
.
.
```

Comment: It does not answers my question

Comment: So, which part is unclear?

Comment: I have whole date and time , can you write that code for me , for my column

Comment: from your example, I assume you have a dataframe `df` with a column 'Timestamp' which contains strings. You'd get Unix time (seconds since 1970-01-01) like `pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"]).astype(int)/1e9`. If you need integer seconds, you'd have to add another `astype(int)`.